# How does SDL OData framework support Open Type?

Tags: odata, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB Document database and I am using the SDL OData framework to plug in the Cosmos DB as the datasource of a OData service. Since Comos DB is schema-agnostic so that any valid JSON can be stored/indexed, the OData service with Cosmos DB datasource needs Open Type support so that undeclared dynamic properties from the input JSON request can be saved in the Cosmos DB.

I checked the EdmEntity notation and found the option to flag it as open, for example:

```
@EdmEntity(namespace = "SDL.OData.Example", key = "id", containerName = "SDLExample", open = true)
```

However, when looking at ODataJsonParser in odata_renderer module of SDL OData, I do not see any support for dynamic fields in the input JSON -- they are just ignored.

How is Open Type supposed to work in SDL OData?

Any help/hints/suggestions will be appreciated.